# Hashed pattern in bargraphs - MS excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am drawing graphs for a paper that supports only black and white graphs.  I need to show more than 3 histograms and want to have different patterns on them like hash, dotted, double hashed etc instead of different colors in the legend.

I am using MS Excel 2007.

I tried but dont find a way except for the option available in design tab that I find when I double click on the chart area( These are shades of grey color and I want patterns like hashing, dots etc).
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

use the shades of gray style and manually change each bar you want to have a pattern:

1. righ-click on the bar
2. choose Format data series
3. choose Fill in the left column of the dialog box
4. choose Pattern fill in the right column